# query to deliver difference between two most recent dates for all products

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, union

i have a database that looks like the following:

```
person | product    |    purchase_time
-------+------------+---------------------
jim    | football   | 2013-02-28 00:01:00
jane   | basketball | 2013-02-28 01:01:00
ben    | baseball   | 2013-02-28 02:02:00
jim    | basketball | 2013-02-28 00:01:00
jim    | basketball | 2013-02-28 00:03:00
jim    | football   | 2013-02-28 00:04:00
jane   | baseball   | 2013-02-28 00:05:00
jane   | football   | 2013-02-28 00:08:00
jane   | basketball | 2013-02-28 01:03:00
ben    | baseball   | 2013-02-28 03:02:00
```

i need a report to run that will tell me the difference (in seconds) between the two most recent dates that a 'person' bought any two products.

so, for instance, if i use footballs and basketballs, i need to know something like:

```
 jim  | 60
 jane | 3180
```

the results coming from the fact that jim's most recent football and basketball purchases came 60 seconds apart (at 04:00 and 03:00), and jane's football and basketball purchases came at 3180 seconds apart (at 08:00, and 01:03, respectively).

i'm able to do this on a person-by-person basis with a loop, where i can use a query like:

```
     SELECT a.person,
       abs(DATE_PART('epoch', a.purchase_time - b.purchase_time)
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM mytable
   WHERE person = 'jim'
     AND product = 'football'
   ORDER BY purchase_time LIMIT 1) a,
  (SELECT *
   FROM mytable
   WHERE person = 'jim'
     AND product = 'basketball'
   ORDER BY purchase_time LIMIT 1) b
```

but in order to see the results for every person, i'd have to execute this query over a loop.

i'm sure there is a smarter way to do this, and i just don't know what it is.

can anyone offer any suggestions?  i am using Postgres 8.1.23.

Comment: Your sample results should show additional field, to make clear what rows are used in each case. I can see a few different possible answers, depending on what assumptions I make about your desired question.

Comment: @Jason: why didn't you included ben in your result? for each person 1 smallest timespan?

Comment: [PostgreSQL 8.1 is long dead and forgotten and unsupported (EOL in 2010)](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Please consider upgrading to a modern version.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens - please let me know which assumptions you want me to nail down.

Comment: @deblendewim - ben's appearance is optional.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - easier said than done when you're talking about deployed boxes across the US.  it's on the list, but isn't a priority.  unfortunately, it's not a luxury i have at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select person, abs(DATE_PART('epoch', p1 - p2) 
from (select person,
             MAX(case when product = 'football' then purchase_time end) as p1,
             MAX(case when product = 'basketball' then purchase_time end) as p2
      from mytable
      group by person
     ) p
where p1 is not null and p2 is not null
```

I'm interpreting the question as the most recent purchase of Product A and the most recent of Product B, not the most recent of the two products (which could both be Product A, for instance).

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted, except for one thing.  this finds the earliest difference in dates, not the latest.  i'll play with the query and see if i can make it work.  also, you need another parenthesis after the DATE_PART ending parenthesis.